# Is there any general formula for $S = 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \dotsb+(n - 1)^{n - 1} + n^n, n \in N$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Is there any general formula to sum following series:

$$S = 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \dotsb+(n - 1)^{n - 1} + n^n, n \in N$$

I mean for $S = f(n)$, is there a formula to compute $f(n)$?

Comment: It seems to me a possible duplicate, but I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Yes, indeed: look for Faulhaber's formula.

Comment: Nope, sorry. This is equivalent to the integral of $x^x$. Faulhaber's formula is about polynomials.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Indeed, Faulhaber's formula is for sums of the form $\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} k^p$, where $p \geq 1$ is fixed.

Comment: In general, if there isn't an elementary integral for a function there will not be a partial sum formula either.

Comment: I found the first few values (for $n = 1, \dots , 4$), and this sequence (not surprisingly) [appears in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001923).  You can find more information there.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral

Comment: @GregRos, @ JavaMan You are right, sorry.

Comment: Here is a list: http://oeis.org/A001923/b001923.txt

Comment: http://ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf

Comment: @vesszabo I remember this question as well, but I don't think it has any answers...

Comment: We have the upper bound $f(n-1)<n^n$, which I only managed to observe from sheer calculations

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a closed form exists, but an asymptotic approximation can be given as
$$
\begin{align}
&n^n\left(1+\frac1n\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^{n-1}}+\frac1{n^2}\frac{(n-2)^{n-2}}{n^{n-2}}+\frac1{n^3}\frac{(n-3)^{n-3}}{n^{n-3}}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{n^n\left(1+\frac1{en}+\frac{3+e}{2e^2n^2}+\frac{52+60e+7e^2}{24e^3n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)}
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{(n-k)^{n-k}}{n^{n-k}}\right)
&=(n-k)\left(-\frac kn-\frac{k^2}{2n^2}-\frac{k^3}{3n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\\
&=-k+\frac{k^2}{2n}+\frac{k^3}{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)
\end{align}
$$
and so
$$
\frac1{n^k}\frac{(n-k)^{n-k}}{n^{n-k}}
=e^{-k}\left(\frac1{n^k}+\frac{k^2}{2n^{k+1}}+\frac{3k^4+4k^3}{24n^{k+2}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{k+3}}\right)\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

From [simple graphing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ae5qifhaxw), I've managed to find really good bounds for your function:

$$\log_{10}(f(n))\le\frac{\ln(n^n)}{2.301}$$

I have no guarantee that my inequalities will hold true, but they most certainly hold true from graphing for $20\le n\le143$, which is decently large.

If your wondering how I derived this, I took a guess at how fast $f(n)$ grew and attempted to derive a formula with equivalent growth, seeing that $n^n<f(n)<(n+1)^{n+1}$, we can see how fast it grows, and I just took the log of it to keep numbers manageable.

From a [nice article](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf), I took the most understandable parts of it to see that for $n>2$,

$$n^n\left(\frac{4n-3}{4n-4}\right)\le f(n)\le n^n\left(\frac{2+e(n-1)}{e(n-1)}\right)$$

At proposition 2.1.

Comment: Your bounds are asymptotically $n^n\left(1+\frac1{4n}\right)$ and $n^n\left(1+\frac2{en}\right)$. As computed in my answer, $f(n)\sim n^n\left(1+\frac1{en}\right)$, which fits nicely between your bounds.

Comment: @robjohn Oh, nice.